# Executing zgrep recursively in Linux

Tags: linux, perl, grep

This zgrep command is outputting a particular field of a line containing the word yellow when given a giant input log file for all 24 hours of 26th Feb 1989.

```
zgrep 'yellow' /color_logs/1989/02/26/*/1989-02-26-00_* | cut -f3 -d'+'
```

1) I prefer using a perl script.  Are there advantages of using a bash script?

Also when writing this script I would like for it to create a file after processing the data for each DAY (so it will look at all the hours in a day)

```
zgrep 'yellow' /color_logs/1989/02/*/*/1989-02-26-00_* | cut -f3 -d'+'
```

2) How do I determine the value of the first star (in Perl), after processing a day's worth of data so that I can output the file with the YYMMDD in its name.  I'm interested in getting the value of the first star from the line of code directly above this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep writes out the file that where the line came from, but your cut command is throwing that away.  You could do something like:

```
open(PROCESS, "zgrep 'yellow' /color_logs/1989/02/*/*/1989-02-26_* |");
while(<PROCESS>) {
    if (m!/color_logs/(\d\d\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d)/[^:]+:(.+)$!) {
        my ($year, $month, $day, $data) = ($1, $2, $3, $4);
        # Do the cut -f3 -d'+' on the line from the log
        my $data = (split('+', $data))[2];
        open(OUTFILE, ">>${year}${month}${day}.log");
        print OUTFILE $data, "\n";
        close(OUTFILE);
    }
}
```

That's inefficient in that you're opening and closing the file for each line, you could use an IO::File object instead and only open when the date changes, but you get the idea.